# Image upload in one click - Onchange not being triggered

Tags: javascript, html, image

Below is a simple script to **upload image in one click**. Once the user browses and picks a picture, it gets uploaded right away.

For some reasons, this script was working fine until recently, and now **nothing happens once the user chooses an image.**

```
<div class="upload_button">
    <form action="upload.php" id="upload_icon" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-
        data">
        <input class="upload" id="file" type="file" name="image" style="display:none"
        />
        <img class="upload_img" src="images/icon.png">
    </form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.upload_img').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.upload').click();
    });

    document.getElementById("file").onchange = function () {
        document.getElementById("upload_button").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Would this issue has anything to do with .onchange ?

Comment: This link should clear you up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952804/onchange-event-doesnt-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user2550807's comment, I was able to fix my issue.

I applied an addEventListener to the DOM object.

So I changed :

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
document.getElementById("upload_button").submit();
}
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", function() {
document.getElementById("upload_button").submit();
});
```